# Question answering engine

Tags: software-development, web-services

We are looking for a question answering engine for a website.

How we will see such a system in an ideal world:

### 1. From the site visitor's point of view

- A visitor opens a page on our site (e.g. Help/support/FAQ/"more info" page) and see a big "ask your question here" box and possibly some FAQ (created dynamically) under it.
- The visitor types their question. The system automatically suggests some previously asked questions when the user enters at least 2 letters.
- The system finds the existing question that most closely matches the given request and the corresponding answer in the database.
- After that it can also to validate the found answer with the user (if they are happy with the answer)
- If they don't, the system can ask for contact information to send the right answer later.

### 2. From the site administrator's point of view

- There is a list of questions that the administrator can manage (add, edit, delete, merge, set some settings, etc).
- There is a list of queries (visitor requests) with some useful information for each query (when it was asked, where the user was from, were they satisfied with the answer, etc)
- There is also a list of "unsolved" queries. The admin can associate each with a question or create a new question/answer pair to cover a similar case in the future.

The system must learn from the users' reactions and eventually provide more accurate answers and suggest the admins add additional information for the cases which are not satisfying at the moment.

Are there some ready-to-use solutions for the described requirements?